# Magento 2 Customer session logsout automatically

Tags: magento2, customer-session, logout

We are in Magento 2.3.6 version. Recently on our website, we are facing customer session logout issues randomly.

1. Customer login redirects to the same login page without any session set.
2. Forgot password emails are not sent to customers.
3. On the checkout page when the submit Order button is clicked, the session gets logout.
4. After placing an order, the session gets logout and the success page loads as a 404 page since there is no customer session.

All these above issues are happening randomly in different scenarios. We couldn't reproduce it sometimes. We know there is some issue with the session. But we couldn't find or debug what it is exactly?

Comment: check your recent actions, did you remove/install new modules/themes, did you change any settings? or simply verify free space in your hard disk

Comment: @Jimmy We didn't do any recent changes. Will free space solve the issue?

Comment: it's a machine, not a human. it has to have something changed, nothing happens out of blue, so I suggest you check your last actions, or simply rollback daily update. No one can give you solution without actually checking your store

Comment: @Agnes regarding the checkout issues, you might want to check this out: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049032952-Customers-get-logged-out-or-lose-cart-content-on-Magento-storefront